# Polymer 2.0 - Trying to create HTML template from JSON with events

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I am trying to create HTML templates from JSON object and able to render elements but the events are not getting added to the element and not showing up in the developer tools/Shadow DOM.

Codepen for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/bRjWbd

**Issue**: Events - **onkeypress, onkeyup,onchange** are not showing on input and checkbox elements and couldn't add them but other options are showing up like name, type(Again **type** is getting displayed only for checkbox but not for textbox)

Screenshot for actual issue

[image]

HTML:

```
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/">
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-collapse/iron-collapse.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo attr='[{
               "type":"text",
               "title":"Textbox Name",
               "name":"temp",
               "requried":"requried",
               "onkeypress":"testKeyPress()",
               "onkeyup":"testKeyUp()",
               "onchange":""  
              },{
               "type":"checkbox",
               "title":"CheckBox Name",
               "name":"temp",
               "requried":"requried",
               "disabled":"disabled",
               "onkeypress":"",
               "onkeyup":"",
               "onchange":"testChange()" 
              }]'></x-foo>


  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{attr}}">
             <label>{{item.title}}</label>
             <input type="{{item.type}}"
                    required="{{item.required}}"
                    name="{{item.name}}"
                    onchange="{{item.onchange}}"
                    onkeypress="{{item.onkeypress}}"
                    onkeyup="{{item.onkeyup}}()"
                    >
         </template>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

JS:

```
  class XFoo extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() { return 'x-foo'; }

    static get properties() {
      return {
        attr:{
          type:Array
        }
      };

    }


  }
  customElements.define(XFoo.is, XFoo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it should be:

```
   on-change="{{item.onchange}}"
   on-keypress="{{item.onkeypress}}"
   on-keyup="{{item.onkeyup}}()"
```

Reference: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/gesture-events

Comment: problem is that , if you see the shadow DOM Tree for input , onkeyup / on-keyup both events are not added